# MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I am new in iphone using `MKMapView` to load a google's map in my application .But its throwing an exception "MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.". So where should I initialise my `MKMapView` object. I am initializing in `viewDidLoad()`.

thanks in advance.....

Comment: You really should provided more details...

Answer (score 3):

The reason it isn't being creating on the main thread is one of 2 options

1. The View that creates it lives on one of the background threads
2. You are are calling `performSelectorInBackground:` to create your view

To perform a function on the Main Thread call  `performSelectorOnMainThread:`

Off-topic: If the function requires more then 1 parameter, change it to an NSDictionary and load all of your settings into the Dictionary and pass it in eg

```
NSDictionary *params = ...... //load your parameters into here

[myMapView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initMap:)
                                withObject:params
                             waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Also read the following [First](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=forcing%20a%20call%20on%20the%20main%20thread%20iOS&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html&ei=5EkMT_r3GIiaiQeEop36BQ&usg=AFQjCNFXoxOJXag9JgBwIeIL7BYeGExjfQ&cad=rja) and [Second](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=forcing%20a%20call%20on%20the%20main%20thread%20iOS&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDUQFjAD&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html&ei=5EkMT_r3GIiaiQeEop36BQ&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&cad=rja) to get a better understanding of multithreading in iOS

Comment: I am using following code in viewDidLoad and this view is called by another view

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,780,920)];
    mapView.delegate=self; 
    
    [self.view addSubview:mapView]; 
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayMyMap) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: You are creating a new thread by doing that, try to change to performSelectorOnMainThread instead of detachNewThreadSelector

Comment: thanks for your suggesion but still i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 3, the following will ensure your function runs on the main thread.
OperationQueue.main.addOperation{"your segue or function call"}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please wrap your code with backticks so that it is displayed as code.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

> MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread

When I tried to change the content of a customized `UITableViewCell` in this way:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[myIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

The UITableviewCell in the corresponding indexpath contained a MKMapView that I tried to change its region.

myTabelViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];
[cell setContentWithLatitude:currentLatitude longitude:currentLongitude];
```

Use the above code instead of `[self.tableView reloadData]` to refresh just one cell.